# How to use an OpenCycleMap API key in OpenStreetMap R package?

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I'm using the `openmap()` function from `OpenStreetMap` to pull down some tiles from OpenCycleMap. 
This line has worked until recently when tiles started having a watermark of 'API Key needed'

```
map = openmap(map_extent$upperLeft, map_extent$lowerRight,zoom=map_extent$zoom, minNumTiles=9,type='OpenCycleMap',mergeTiles = T)
```

I've gone through the process to obtain an API key, I'm just not sure how to actually format the `type` argument to use the API key successfully.

The package documentation shows this example:

```
Some maps from custom urls:
apiKey <- paste0("?access_token=",
"pk.eyJ1IjoidGhlZmVsbCIsImEiOiJjaXN1anNwODEwMWlrMnRvZHBhamRrZjlqIn0.Gf8qLSpZ6yo5yfQhEutFfQ")
baseUrl <- "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}"
map <- openmap(c(43.46886761482925,119.94873046875),
c(33.22949814144951,133.9892578125),
minNumTiles=4,
type=paste0(baseUrl,apiKey))
```

and I've used

```
baseUrl<-"https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=[my api key]"
map = openmap(map_extent$upperLeft, map_extent$lowerRight,zoom=map_extent$zoom, minNumTiles=9,type=baseUrl,mergeTiles = T)
```

but without success: I get an

> Error in osmtile(x%%nX, y, zoom, type) : 
>     could not obtain tile: 2102 14443 15

I've tried multiple zoom levels to try to get different tiles without success, and have checked the OpenCycleMap website to confirm it's still up, I'm just not sure where to go next

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the function myself but from looking at your post I think the error might be with the {s}-part of the url. This has to be substituted to a, b, c or deleted completely for the request to work.

My guess is that openmap only substitutes x/y/z but not the s and so the request is not valid. Try changing it to:

```
baseUrl<-"https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=[my api key]"
```

If that works you can just use it or implement your own cycling through a/b/c to achieve better performance.